# How to put a mattress cover back on?

Tags: bedroom

When washing my top mattress covers, or even if only taking them off and putting them back on, I always have trouble putting them back on without the (foam) mattress buckling inside, making bumps that are uncomfortable to sleep on. It seems like the mattress is slightly too big for the cover, so it should be slightly compressed inside the cover, but putting it on makes the compression uneven or it bends instead of compressing.

Are there any tricks to put these covers on while keeping the mattress smooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tricks which my family has been using when doing this.  Unfortunately it still requires some work.

First of all you should stretch it directly after washing to regain some of the size it had before washing. Especially try stretching the width of the covers. Do avoid tumble dryers as they tend to shrink it even more.

Secondly, when inserting the mattress into the cover bend it halfway along the longest side before sliding it in. Then it is a matter of aligning the corners with each other. This does usually demand a little patience, time and fumbling.

If you find yourself way off, you might need to bend the mattress again a little too get leverage for moving the cover.

Good luck (or rather "Lykke til")!

Answer (score 2):

After washing the cover of my queen size Ikea mattress I couldn't get it back on. 
The cover tended to grab on the mattress, and refused to slide on smoothly.
The solution was to stand the mattress against a wall and fold a polypropylene (plastic) tarpaulin over the upper edge of the mattress just far enough so it stayed put, covering one face and the sides of the mattress. 
I was then able to slide the mattress cover on fairly easily over the smooth polypropylene tarp. 
Once the cover was almost fully in place I layed the mattress on the floor and pulled the tarp out. Because the polypropylene is very strong I could pull really hard on it without it tearing. 
Final closure of the mattress cover was fairly easy after that. See the photo.[image: Using a plastic tarp to help slide the cover back on a mattress]

Answer (score -1):

Stand mattress on edge then put cover over end of mattress zip up slowly.

Comment: Welcome! I struggle with picturing the process. Could you please explain the details? Are you assuming the type of mattress covers with a zipper all around or at least on three sides? I don’t see how this could work for the “slip on like a sock” type. I recommend an [edit]. Apart from that, the [tour] and the [help] are good spots to learn more about how the site works.